# How can I remove one row from a table and insert it into another via a SQL statement?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

My SQL statement works fine without the delete statement which is my problem.
I use 2 OleDbCommands to call the seperate queries.
This is my current SQL statement in C#:

```
string mysql = "Insert Into Completed([Batch number], [Product], [Weight]) VALUES('" + batchNumber + "','" + product + "','" + weight + "')";
```

string newsql = "DELETE FROM Dryers WHERE [Batch number]='"+batchNumber+"'";

This my latest failed attempt in code:

```
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {

            try
            {
                using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope tScope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    string batchNumber = txtBatchNumber3.Text.ToString();
                    string product = txtProduct3.Text.ToString();
                    string weight = txtWeight3.Text.ToString();

                    string mysql = "Insert Into Packing([Batch number], [Product], [Weight]) VALUES('" + batchNumber + "','" + product + "','" + weight + "') ";
                    string newsql = "DELETE * FROM Dryers WHERE [Batch number]='" + batchNumber + "'";

                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(mysql, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(newsql, conn);
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    tScope.Complete();

                }


                MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfuly...!");
                this.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed due to" + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();                    
            }
            }                
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
        }

    }
    }
}
```

VS2012 gives the following error:

> Failed due toData type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Are you querying MySQL or Access?  Why have you tagged both?

Comment: It was suggested to me. Querying Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two statements but wrap them in a transaction so it's a single unit of work.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
COMMIT
```

if you wanted to do it in C# then you would wrap your queries in a transaction scope.

```
using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope tScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    //do work here
    //if work is completed
    tScope.Complete();

    //else do nothing the using statement will dispose the scope and rollback your changes.
}
```

Here is a walkthrough from Microsoft about making the connection against an access database and querying using ADO.NET.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx

Comment: modified my solution to include C# syntax as well.

Comment: still the same error. failed due to data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: what is the type of the [Batch Number] field? You have that wrapped in single quotes, is it really a string field or numeric?

Comment: It is numeric. It Inserts with no problem, but just doesn't want to delete the record.

Comment: Removing the single quotes did the trick. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in Access. You have to call two separate SQL strings.

Comment: Ok, thank you. i always try and go for the shortest and easiest way.

Comment: The following errors occurs : The best overload method match as some invalid arguments. Also cannot convert from string to "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection" And cannot convert from "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection" to "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbTransaction"

Comment: Why won't it work? He is using same connection. He can modify his query a bit something like `"insert into tbl1 values(1, 2); delete from tbl2;"`

Comment: Don't know why. It just doesn't - by design.

Comment: So there is no solution?

Comment: There is. Look above. And if needed, wrap the calls in a transaction as shown by Rob.